# magento running apache virtualhost, backend not saving changes

Tags: backend

I have setup two websites, **http://www.firstsite.com** and **http://www.secondsite.com** on one server using apache virtualhost.

The issue is when I login to **http://www.secondsite.com/index.php/admin** I can edit but not save the changes.  If i try to save it redirects  back to **http://www.secondsite.com**

Note: If i delete the var/cache then I able to save the changes.  But i have to keep doing this every time.

Anyone know where the issue might lie?  Or maybe point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem in case someone has a similar issue in the future.

In short the problem has nothing to do with having two sites running under apache virtualhost.  The solution is: go to magento database--->core_config_data and search for **secure** and **unsecure** base url.  In my case mysecondsite.com was missing "www".  Changing this to www.mysecondsite.com fixed the issues mentioned above.